# What should an iOS cordova project structure look like?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm quite new to Xcode (5.1), and I'm trying to build up a cordova application.
Basically, I created a new project using cordova through the CLI. I also added several cordova plugins this way.
And I replaced the original hello world `www` folder with the one of my project.

I get one issue, `"Semantic Issue", Method definition for 'makeEntryForPath:isDirectory:' not found`. and there seems to be a silent JS crash of the app on the testing device.

`File` is the first plugin I installed, and I guess it's not found, because not located at the right place.
In fact, I'm quite confused with the Xcode directory structure, which present several duplicates. There's a `config.xml` and a `www` directory at the root level. Some others are in a `Staging` directory. Plugins are located at the root directory as well. But I noticed that I had to manually copy some files in the `Staging/www/js` folder, where it seems that the app is looking for, as told by Safari's remote debugger...

Do you know where I could find a general overview of what a cordova/Xcode project structure with plugins should look like?

Thanks

Comment: The `platforms` directory should be considered a build artifact. In other words: ignore it. The bigger question is can you build the project using `cordova build ios` and do you get the same errors? If so try removing the iOS platform and adding it back `cordova platform remove ios`, `cordova platform add ios`. Sounds silly, but more often than not this has fixed some oddball compilation errors on my part. If that still fails, remove the plugin and add it back just to make sure you didn't get a corrupted download.

Comment: Also, make sure you're editing your `www` code in the root level and not anywhere else. If you don't, `cordova prepare`/`build` will wipe out all your changes.

Comment: Fine, I just re-setup a brand new project from scratch using the CLI. I added plugins. And the Hello World is working. From there, what would be the ideal process? I only update the `myapp/www` folder. And then I build the app from the CLI to copy the changes to the iOS folder. And I finally launch it on the device from Xcode?

Comment: I added `cordova.js` for iOS to my `www\js\lib`directory, where my HTML page expect it to be. Then, I noticed that `cordova_plugin.js`was not found either. I therefore copied it to the same location. Now, I can see that the app can't find all the .js files related to the plugins. Do I have to copy all these .js files manually ? And where should they be ?

Comment: Indeed -- you work only in the root `www` directory. You can keep Xcode open if you want, but to get Xcode to see the changes, you'd need to run `cordova prepare` prior to running it on the device. That said, you can run the app on a device using `ios-sim`/`ios-deploy` if installed. `cordova run ios` will use those if available. `cordova emulate ios` will launch the iOS simulator without having Xcode open as well.

Comment: Don't worry about your `cordova*.js` files -- `cordova prepare`/`cordova build` ensures that they are in the project-level files and in the correct spot. But they won't exist in your top-level `www` directory, and that's OK.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! It's working now (at least I can debug the JS with no issues on Xcode). Thanks for your explanations. Those were not obvious on the Cordova documentation...